# jQuery: Help re-activating button when limit is reduced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have built this simple application where you can add input boxes using a button. Then when the limits reached it prevents you adding more and it has a maximum input box message displayed. You also have the option to remove the boxes you've just added. The problem I'm having is I don't know how to re-active the add button when the user has removed some of the input boxes. I'm pretty new to jQuery so if theres a better way of writing the code then I'm all ears. I have re-created my example in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jTh3v/367/.

The way I was looking to do it was when you clicked a remove button like such:

```
$("#remove").click(function(e){
  $("#MAX").hide('<p>MAX</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your

```
$("#Input").on("click","#remove", function(e){
```

In order to reenable the add button you need:

```
$("#add").prop("disabled",false);
```

To remove the MAX message you can:

```
$("#MAX p:first").remove();
```

The updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTh3v/373/).

Here the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 5;
  var x = 1;

  $("#add").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
      x++;
      $("#Input").append(
        '<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a></div>'
      );
    } else if(x == max_fields){
      $("#MAX").append('<p>MAX</p>');
      $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    }
  });

  $("#Input").on("click","#remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    x--;
    $("#add").prop("disabled",false);
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
    $("#MAX p:first").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="add">Add</button><hr>
<input type="text" name="mytext[]">
<div id="Input"></div>
<div id="MAX"></div>
```

Comment: you don't need this conditional `if (x<=0) { x = 0; return; }` as the the first conditional `if(x < max_fields){` will have to be greater than 0 to be true

Comment: @SergioAlen Thanks so much. If I do not have elements to remove I cannot decrease the x.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
  $("#Input").on("click","#remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
  });
```

Try this:

```
  $("#Input").on("click","#remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
    x--;
    $("#add").prop("disabled",false);
    $("#MAX").find('p').remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to re-enable the add button, add `$('#add').prop('disabled', false);` to the remove `click` event handler.

Also, for the MAX display, I would recommend putting `<p>Max</p>` in the html, and setting the `#MAX` div to `style="display:none;"`, then using `$('#MAX').show()` and `$('#MAX').hide()` to display the MAX indicator. If you follow my instructions and add the above code to re-enable the add button, you'll see why:

1. The MAX indicator remains on the page after the button is re-enabled
2. Once you re-enable the add button, and then click it again until you reach the max number of fields for a second time, an additional `<p>MAX</p>` gets added to the `div`, creating duplicate indicators.

Answer (score 0):

In the `#remove` click event handler

```
$("#Input").on("click", "#remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
});
```

add the following line to update the `disabled` property of `#add`:

```
$('#add').prop('disabled', false);
```

Example:

```
$("#Input").on("click", "#remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    $('#add').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#MAX').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way

```
$("#Input").on("click","#remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    $('#MAX').html('');
    if( x===4 ){
        $('#add').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Its enabling  Add button once, when you removed your fifth element.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTh3v/372/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the limit is greater than the number of input field when you delete one of them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 5;
  var x = 1;

  $("#add").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
      x++;
      $("#Input").append(
        '<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a></div>'
      );
    }else if(x == max_fields){
        $("#MAX").append('<p>MAX</p>');
      $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    }
  });

  $("#Input").on("click","#remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;

    if(x < max_fields){  //here you check if lower than limit
       $('#add').prop("disabled", false);
       $("#MAX").html(''); //deleting the content of max
    }

  });
});
```

[Here is the jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rshLr993/1/)